# Ajax Calender does not pop up on text box focus

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.0

So I've been trying to get the CalendarExtender from the Ajaxcontroltoolkit to work in my web application and all with no success. I started off trying to use the little calendar picture to make it popup, but the page kept reloading when it was clicked and I could not find any solutions online. I read  that if I did not choose a popup image it would activate when the textbox came into focus, so i cleared the property...but still nothing what am I missing?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CustomerSignUpDate"
    style="z-index: 1; left: 1px; top: 0px; position: relative; height: 21px;"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calendarButtonExtender"
runat="server" TargetControlID="CustomerSignUpDate"
Format="MM-dd-yyyy" StartDate="2012-06-20"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I accidentally deleted everything on my server last night and had to redeploy my web application....and what do ya know..IT FIXED ITSELF.

So I say, make sure you have all the references in your project and perhaps delete everything on the server and do a fresh deploy.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CustomerSignUpDate"
        style="z-index: 1; left: 1px; top: 0px; position: relative; height: 21px;"/>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calendarButtonExtender"
    runat="server" TargetControlID="CustomerSignUpDate"
    Format="MM-dd-yyyy" StartDate="2012-06-20"/>
</div>
```